# Which grant type to use to authenticate third party client for API access?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am building third party APIs for first time. I have a laravel app using passport for authentication. I am building some APIs to provide my content to other partners. I have been researching about which grant type to use for this type of scenario.

First one comes to my mind is **client credential grant**. But there is no user associated to this grant type, which will be difficult in keeping API access track(to generate client wise API access report) and No refresh token is provided in this.

Second is **password grant type**. This method has user and also provides refresh token. But I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Can anyone suggest which grant type to use for this type of scenario? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you thinking about grant types if you are just a consumer of a token? If you are building an API, you should get an access token, validate it (validity, scopes) and perform the operation or deny it.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to associate the end user with the client, have you looked into using OpenID Connect? It'd probably use the authorization_code or implicit flow, depending on how your architecture looks.

Comment: @rj2700 I don't need to connect end user to client. its just me and client. I am giving my curated content to client.

Comment: @JánHalaša Right, I think I should drop the idea of using laravel passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can use the [personal access token method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens). The personal access token is a long-lived token which you can't revoke or refresh the token but you can adjust its expiration.

Comment: That is also a good option. But I shifted to simple JWT-Auth, cause I think the OAuth2 is not needed in this case.

Comment: I am not sure with JWT-Auth but personal access token is prepared for service-based solutions.